# Merge two rows and remove duplicates per cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to merge two rows and at the same time remove duplicates.

For merging Im using `=TEXTJOIN(" ,";TRUE;UNIQUE(A2:B2))`

This merges the rows but keep duplicates. How can I merge and remove duplicates at the same time? Im using excel 16 (OS X).

[image]

Comment: Not tested because I don't have Excel365 here but I think you should use [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) first, remove duplicates and then TEXTJOIN...

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thanks, tried a few examples after googling (before i created this thread) but havent had any sucess so not sure how to use textsplit in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "*Im using excel 16 (OS X)*"

I'm confused or simply unaware about OS X Excel versions, but how are you using `TEXTJOIN()`? Is this actually available in Excel 16 OSX for you? Are you using UDF's instead of native functions?

If you so happen to actually use ms365, try something along these lines:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1&", "&B1,", "),1))
```

A long way 'round for OS:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1&", "&B1,", ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1)+LEN(B1)+2)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1&", "&B1),,,LEN(A1&", "&B1)),LEN(A1&", "&B1)))))
```

Comment: Yes, im using TEXTJOIN; i gave an example for merging (that works) in my question. The example you gave give me a "There's a problem with this formula." so it doesnt work with Excel for mac Unfortunately

Comment: Excel 2016 does **not** support `TEXTJOIN()`, so please enlighten me/us. Are you using macros? @Jerry. This would explain why you are finding trouble using `TEXTSPLIT()`.

Comment: Oh. Its excel for mac 16.52 but with a ms365 subcription, and im using this formula: `=TEXTJOIN(" ,";TRUE;UNIQUE(A2:B2))` - i googled and it seems `TEXTSPLIT()` is only available for 16.50 for the Mac version. Ill try to update it and see if that helps.

Comment: @Jerry, that's not true when I look at the official [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7), which states `Mac: 16.65 (Build 220911)`. Have you tried to update your Excel btw?

Comment: @Jerry This is a US site and we use the US list separator when posting. So you need to replace the commas with semicolons for the formulas to work, the same as me and many others. Also, when posting, you should replace your semicolons with commas.

Comment: @JvdV I ment is only available for 16.50 and up, and Im below that version. Gonna update but needs IT´s help with that so will test as soon as I can.

Comment: @Jerry, so 16.52 is below 16.50? Anyway, if you can't work it out with IT, there are other ways around your issue. I might update my answer soon.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks! Of course. That removed my error but gave me a invalid name error instead (#NAME?)

Comment: @JvdV I can update but I need to get the authorization code from App store and I cant get hold of the person with this device until after lunch. So Ill test it soon Edit: Im blind 16.60 is correct, not 16.50 for TEXTSPLIT

Comment: @Jerry, good luck for later. For now; I edited in an alternative to `TEXTSPLIT()`.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, forumla worked but didnt remove duplicates so no different form my original formula unfortunately

Comment: @Jerry, stange. Worked for me.

Comment: @JvdV I got it to work! I have to convert the commas and made a mistake doing so, this worked for me:  `=TEXTJOIN(", ";;UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1&", "&B1;", ";REPT(" ";LEN(A1)+LEN(B1)+2));SEQUENCE(LEN(A1&", "&B1);;;LEN(A1&", "&B1));LEN(A1&", "&B1))))) ` Thanks!